Keyboard-Shortcut to Open Safari Web Extension Popup
Is it possible to open a Safari WEB Extension popup through a command or keyboard shortcut?
I have a Safari Web Extension whose popup I want to access quickly through a Command or Keyboard Shortcut. I don't care if the configuration for this is inside or outside the extension's code.
The main problem I have is that, since this is a Safari WEB Extension (not App), it's more difficult to interact with Safari functionalities.
From what I could find, there’s no built-in way to do it, but a workaround could be to add an event listener in content.js and then send a message to SafariWebExtensionHandler through browser.runtime.sendNativeMessage inside background.js to open the popup. I couldn’t find anything on how to do the latter.
content.js
document.addEventListener('keydown', function(event) {
    // Check if the Control key is pressed
    if (event.ctrlKey) {
        console.log('Control key pressed!');
        browser.runtime.sendMessage("open").then((response) => {
            console.log("Received response: ", response);
        });
    }
});

background.js
browser.runtime.onMessage.addListener((request, sender, sendResponse) => {
    browser.runtime.sendNativeMessage(
      "com.owner.MyExtension",
      "open"
      )
    .then((response) => {
        sendResponse(response.echo);
    });
});

SafariWebExtensionHandler.swift
class SafariWebExtensionHandler: NSObject, NSExtensionRequestHandling {

    func beginRequest(with context: NSExtensionContext) {
        ...
        // YOUR CODE
        ...
    }    
}

What I've tried:

Add "commands" to the manifest.json, but that is only for inside the app commands.
How to open Safari Extension ToolbarItem popover programmatically, but that only works for Safari App Extension. Mine is a Safari WEB Extension. (SFSafariApplication.getActiveWindow doesn't work in this context)

